# How do I open a file that has been signed with CAdES?

Tags: file, digital-signature

I need to sign documents with a CAdES-A signature and have a service that provides this to me.

Now, let's say I sign a GIF file. What I get back from the signing service, if I get it correctly, is an envelope that contains the original document, the signature, and the timestamp.

My problem is that, at least in the tests I did, this is no longer a GIF file, i.e., I can't open it with an image viewer and see the original image.

So my question is: once I sign an arbitrary type of document using CAdES-A, how do I open it to access its original contents?

Please note: my problem is not verifying the signature or timestamp (this works fine), it's really "seeing" the original document. 
Also, I know how to do things for a PDF. It's the "arbitrary format" aspect that is troubling me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to get the original file out of the envelope using openssl:

```
openssl smime -verify -in x-click-but04.p7s -inform DER -signer certificate.cer -noverify -out x.gif
```

Where

- certificate.cer is the certificate used for signing
- x-click-but04.p7s is the enveloping signature, containing signature + original file +
  timestamp
- x.gif (the output file) is the original file that is being extracted from the envelope

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, wrapping signature hides the original data format, making the data "unusable".
The library or service which validates the signature also should provide access to original data - just re-check its API. Or use another API if it's not available.

The alternative is to use detached signatures - they are stored and held separately and they don't change original file. This would work if your code both creates and verifies signatures (I think most third parties would expect a single signed data block rather than a detached signature).